# How do you use yup context in test()

Tags: yup

How do I check against values provided in the context-option for `yup` in the `test()`-function?

The documentation is clear on how to use *context* in when but it is less clear for *test*-functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [runkit](https://npm.runkit.com/yup) we can see that the context for the test i is buried under options in the `test()` context, i.e. it is not the same as for `when()`:

```
var yup = require("yup")

const name = yup.string()
    .label('A name of strings')
    .test(
  'not-taken',
  '${path} is already already takem',
  (value, { options: { context: { values } } }) => value !== values);

const options = { context: { values:  'Olof'  }}
console.log(name.validateSync('Jimmy', options), 'validated')
console.log(name.validateSync('Olof', options), 'validated')
```

Still unclear is how the proper TypeScript declaration of context should be.